# How to update my google play services libraries?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I need `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1` in my project, but in my `/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/` where it should be, there are versions only up to `9.4.0`. How do I add the `9.6.1`?

I have mac on El Capitan.

Comment: you need to open the SDK manager and update through there and then edit your `build.gradle` file to the new dependencies

Comment: SDK manager doesn't let me update (it's probably the latest?). It's on revision 38 and `play-services-ads/9.6.1` nowhere to be seen

Comment: Are you using a local maven repository and if so what does the repositories dependency in `build.gradle` look like.

Comment: it's actually npm library and dependency looks like this `dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.6.1'
}`

Comment: Is this purely Android, or are you using a 3rd party?

Comment: I am using react native. but I have figured the problem out. I will add it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, problem was that even though I downloaded the correct package via Android Package Manager, it was installed in a different directory. So if this happens to you, you should look for duplicate android SDK installation, and either edit the project to look for the packages in the correct place or be lazy like me and just copy the needed packages to the desired location. It's probably a bad practice, but it works.